# Unable to run pg_restore on windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, database-backups, database-restore

I have taken the backup using pg_dumpall of Postgres 11 and currently trying to restore it to Postgres 14.1. I am using

`"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin\pg_restore.exe" --file="DB_BKP1.dump" --verbose --host=localhost --port=5432 -U postgres` to restore data but the command is stuck for an hour.

It barely has any data (just a couple of tables having a few rows in each).

I have used the following command to take the backup (and it was executed successfully without any error or warning)

`"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin\pg_dumpall.exe" --file=DB_BKP --verbose --host=localhost --port=5433 --username=postgres`

I went through the Postgres logs but didn't find anything in them.

Edit - I have over 150 different databases in my Postgres setup and to use pg_dump I would have to execute the command for each database. So, I have used pg_dumpall in place of pg_dump. Is there any drawback of using pg_dumpall that one should be aware of?

Comment: Reading the documentation would be a good start: [pg_dumpall](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-dumpall.html) "pg_dumpall is a utility for writing out (“dumping”) all PostgreSQL databases of a cluster into one script file. The script file contains SQL commands that can be used as input to psql to restore the databases. " And see Examples section at bottom of page.

Comment: So to follow up on that: can you explain why you used `pg_dumpall` instead of [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/app-pgdump.html)? (And remember to put that in the post, rather than a comment)

Comment: `pg_dumpall` creates a SQL script. You can't use `pg_restore` to "restore" that. You need to use `psql` to _run_  that script. If you want to use `pg_restore` you need to use `pg_dump` with the "custom format" (`-Fc`)

Comment: Thanks, @a_horse_with_no_name . I was fundamentally wrong using the pg_restore with pg_dumpall. Just out of curiosity, are there any downsides of using pg_dumpall(compared to pg_dump) when I have to take a backup of all the databases present in the cluster?